# Как лучше сделать доп. страницы на сайте?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Есть сайт и там раздел с играми допустим. Как лучше сделать? Создавать отдельные папки с названием игры и в каждой папке создавать файл index.html или сразу без каких либо папок, создавать файл с igra.html?

Вот часть кода (**первый пример**):

```
<h1><a href="wasteland3/">ИГРА</a></h1>
```

Это как щас. То есть wasteland3 это папка, а уже в этой папке находится файл index.html и так с любой игрой.

**Второй пример:**

```
<h1><a href="wasteland3.html">ИГРА</a></h1>
```

Здесь уже без каких либо папок, а просто html файл.

Хз кнш, понятно или нет написал) Но кто понял пожалуйста поясните как лучше? Первый или второй пример?

Comment: вы без бекенда что ли?

Comment: Завсиит только от удобства. Как вам удобнее это потом всё редактировать. А вообще советую использовать CMS или написать свою.

Comment: meine, а причём тут бэкенд понять не могу? То что я описал - это работа с файлами по большей части. Если вам интересно, то могу даже сделать два отдельных "проекта", где будет первый пример и второй. Залить на гит и кинуть ссылку (чтобы вы глянули что именно я хочу).

Comment: @Dunker если вы это делает просто для себя, то не нужен бэкенд. Если как минимум, чтобы люди пользовались продуктом, потребуется минимальный бэк

Comment: @МихаилКамахин Для людей, но смысл вообще в бэкенде если на сайте просто информация?

Comment: @Dunker как минимум, чтобы всё время руками не подключать header/footer и ещё что-то. Так придётся каждой странице(файлу) заново писать header и footer

Comment: @МихаилКамахин всё расписал, если хотите "вывести в свет", то нужен минимальный бекенд, тогда и будет проще, чтобы не приходилось при каждом создании игры заводить новый файл и всё прописывать руками по 300 раз

Comment: @МихаилКамахин так значит я туповато делал?) Создал новый отдельный файл (заготовку) и мне остаётся его только скопировать в новую папку для новой игры и потом в этом файле тупо заменить название игры, описание, картинку жанр. Чтобы просто добавить на сайт новую игру, на всё уходит максимум минуты полторы-две. Разве с бэкендом будет быстрее?) Извиняюсь что надоедаю, просто хочу как можно больше узнать об этом)

Comment: @Dunker если у вас там 5-10 страниц максимум, то возможно и не надо делать бэк, ручками всё писать. Если больше или хотите какой-то функционал, чтобы был отклик от сайта (типа награды за прохождение), это надо хранить на бэке. Ну либо в localStorage, если нету важной инфы (пароли, личные данные)

Comment: @МихаилКамахин спасибо за помощь и уделённое время)